# Finding conditional index of an item in a list of objects

Tags: javascript

I need to find index of an item from a list of objects.
First I have to check if that item exist with status of **WAITING**.
If no item with that status exist, then find something else with any other status.
Is there any better solution for this?

x in this code coming from a map

```
MainArray.map((x) => {
    let itemIndex = orders?.findIndex(item => item.status === 'WAITING' && item.slot=== (x));
    if (itemIndex === -1) {
        itemIndex = orders && orders.findIndex(item => item.slot === (x));
    }
    return itemIndex;
}
```

Comment: "better" in what way?

Comment: maybe a single line solution :-)
I feel this code is not good

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a reasonble "single line solution" (those are over-rated in any case; hard to read, hard to debug); but you can avoid searching through the array twice by using a `for` loop:

```
const indexes = MainArray.map((x) => {
    let bySlotIndex;
    for (let index = 0, length = orders?.length; orders && index < length; ++index) {
        const order = orders[index];
        if (item.slot === x) {
            bySlotIndex = bySlotIndex ?? index;
            if (item.status === "WAITING") {
                return index; // Found a waiting one, we're done
            }
        }
    }
    return bySlotIndex ?? -1;
});
```

Or if you really want to use `findIndex`, you can avoid some searching by finding the first one with a matching `slot` first:

```
const indexes = MainArray.map((x) => {
    const bySlotIndex = orders?.findIndex(order => order.slot === x) ?? -1;
    if (bySlotIndex === -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    const waitingIndex = orders.findIndex(
        order => order.status === 'WAITING' && order.slot === x,
        bySlotIndex // Start at the first one with a matching slot
    ); 
    return waitingIndex === -1 ? bySlotIndex : waitingIndex;
});
```

---

Note that both of the above return `-1` if `orders` is falsy, rather than `undefined`. Tweak if you really wanted `undefined`.

Comment: i like the for loop solution. Also got an idea from the second code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` to look for an item with status equal to 'WAITING'. in case, no item exists, use `findIndex` to return the first item with a status.

```js
const arr = [{status: "WAITING", slot : 1}, {status: "NOTWAITING", slot: 2}];

const getIndex = (arr) => {
   const idx = arr.findIndex(x => x.status === 'WAITING');
   return idx !== -1 ? idx : arr.findIndex(x => x.status);
}

console.log(getIndex(arr));
```

Comment: What happened to the `slot` comparison?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - from the explanation of the OP it seems like he just wants to find the index based on the status property.

Comment: The code clearly looks for `item.slot === x`, nothing in the description suggests that that is optional. The answer also changes all the names of things (including using `x` for something completely different from the OP), fails to allow for `orders` (as was) to be falsy, ...